# YouTube is not working after V10.45 version in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-4.4-kitkat, android-youtube-api, tvbox

I have Amlogic s802 TVbox which have Android 4.4.2. I'm using latest version of YouTube app from Playstore and its not working while downgrading YouTube to V10.45 its working fine.

I have another Amlogic s802 development which have 4.4.2 and inside that latest YouTube app is working fine with no issue.

while comparing with both board's logs, I continuously got below error message and there is no **android.hardware.ICameraService** service in TVbox.

> "I/ServiceManager( 3079): Waiting for service media.camera..."

So, my question is:

Does the TVbox require **android.hardware.ICameraService** service to run latest version of YouTube?

Comment: are u trying with offline mode functionality of you tube??

Comment: my above Question may help of you think once around it.